# Is this picture of the melting ice at the North Pole legitimate?

Tags: climate-change, ice

There are multiple stories about the melting of ice at the North Pole, and I know enough about climate science to recognize the seriousness of the issue — my question is *not* about that. I've recently seen a couple stories that have [this picture](https://www.express.co.uk/news/uk/659785/Climate-change-North-Pole-UK-London) or [similar](https://www.google.com/search?q=north%20pole%20ice&tbm=isch&tbs=rimg:CZFNPzXwlOSiIjgrmeySsj81iXl0CLYC-KuqO8keBQPCB1NyqyrW3DRAAjbQgPqStLrzyisUuuiJhPPBjW8srD1ibCoSCSuZ7JKyPzWJEfFQO-IWKsyaKhIJeXQItgL4q6oRqE72Om3vp98qEgk7yR4FA8IHUxEUWykzF8aPKyoSCXKrKtbcNEACER5v3HXOrYaPKhIJNtCA-pK0uvMRY6stFzLi39sqEgnKKxS66ImE8xHUJr3ZR5iSfyoSCcGNbyysPWJsEavHhlFjf7f1&tbo=u&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwivkZO90rvfAhUlq4MKHbUPArEQ9C96BAgBEBg&biw=1866&bih=1018&dpr=1.8#imgrc=cqsq1tw0QALFSM:):
[image]

The caption on a very similar photo at [ABC News](https://abcnews.go.com/International/north-pole-warms-stunningly-high-mid-30s-month/story?id=53388210) reads:

> A sign indicating North Pole is seen among melting ice in this undated file photo.

The word "undated" makes me a tad suspicious. Can anyone find a legitimate provenance for this photo? I'm cautious because it's a very shareable photo, but I don't want to share it if it's an exaggeration of the current state of affairs.

Comment: https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/sign-indicating-north-pole-for-tourists-high-res-stock-photography/123523803

Comment: getty sales the image with and without the sign https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/melting-ice-at-the-geographic-north-pole-high-res-stock-photography/123523848

Comment: Thanks, @DavePhD, does Getty Images suggest that the picture has been sufficiently vetted?

Comment: since they have the same location with and without the sign, it seems suspicious to me.  But I'm not sure enough to answer.  Only know it's been online since before June of 2012, before the lowest arctic ice minimum in September 2012.

Comment: @DavePhD, those two pictures do not appear to me to be the exact same location. Maybe one of the links you provided is incorrect?

Comment: Getty says the 3 (yours and my 2) are all related.  To me, the sign photo looks like a slightly different angle and zoom, but the same place.  My guess is an icebreaker really took tourists to the North Pole, and the photo is really at the North Pole, but the ship necessarily broke the ice. Just a guess.

Comment: There's no physical permanent marker at the north pole because it's all sea-ice which drifts around as new ice forms and old ice melts or shears off.  I'm pretty sure this photo is just meant to be a visual metaphor than the literal truth.

Comment: @GordonM the photographer, Marketa Jirouskova, went to the North Pole on the tourism nuclear icebreaker Yamal.

Comment: @DavePhD, it seems like maybe you've tracked down enough evidence for an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The icebreaker [Yamal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yamal_(icebreaker)) has been traveling to the North Pole since 1994, including tourist trips.

The photographer Marketa Jirouskova [took such a trip to the North Pole](https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/photo/readout-of-first-voyage-to-90-degrees-north-high-res-stock-photography/123538666).

The [official caption of the photo is](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/sign-indicating-north-pole-for-tourists-high-res-stock-photography/123523804) "Sign indicating North Pole for tourists, amongst melting ice, Arctic Ocean "

other related images are [before sticking the sign on the spot](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/melting-ice-at-the-geographic-north-pole-high-res-stock-photography/123523848) and a [different view of after](https://www.gettyimages.com/detail/photo/sign-indicating-north-pole-for-tourists-high-res-stock-photography/123523803)

The only question is how much the icebreaker disturbed the ice in the photo.

For timewise comparison, this is an August 1958 video of waterskiing at the North Pole, when the USS Skate submarine surfaced in open water next to a scientific research group there: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vqWSe6dOgO0

Comment: "The only question is how much the icebreaker disturbed the ice in the photo": I think there's another significant question, which is the distance of the location from the North Pole.  The evidence presented here does not establish that.

Comment: @phoog what about the gps https://www.gettyimages.co.uk/detail/photo/readout-of-first-voyage-to-90-degrees-north-high-res-stock-photography/123538666 ?

Comment: Is there any evidence that the picture of the GPS was taken in the same place or at the same time as the picture of the sign?

Comment: @phoog no absolute proof, just that the photographer is the same.  But look at this video https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=x1XMZTzELaE  starting at about 3:25 for the same sign and how the Yamal places it when the tourists get to the North Pole.